# Nginx and upstream : configuration failed

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I try to test load balancer with nginx so I add upstream like the documentation exemple. But when I try to reload nginx to refresh the configuration, the refresh fail.
I just added upstream bloc, if I remove it all work

file : /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
upstream backend {
    server webserver1:80;
    server webserver2:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.interceptlocalcall.io interceptlocalcall.io;

    location /users {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.10:18000;
    }
...
```

when I reload with the upstream block :

```
[FAIL] Reloading nginx configuration: nginx failed!
```

Nginx version :

```
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
```

I see anything about this error, so I think I just miss something, perhaps in the install ?
If you have any idea thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please test your configuration by running `$ nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t` — it will tell you more detailed information about what's wrong with your configuration.
These messages also written to global error.log file (not one you define for servers but one defined in `http` section), usually located in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Comment: Thanks, I checked with your help my log and finally it's working ! I written my hostname with a mistake so... `host not found`.